# In vite and react, how can I keep a component running in the background despite the router moving?

Tags: reactjs, vite

Unable to operate App component in main.jsx

I want to create App.jsx component in main.jsx, and after rendering, App.jsx continues to work in backGround. may i make main.jsx return in the form of a react function?

**App.jsx**

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("app init");
  }, []);
  return <></>;
}
```

**main.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import router from "../src/router";
import App from "./veiws/main/App";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <RouterProvider router={router} />
);
```

**router.jsx**

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Navigate to="/main" replace />,
  },

  {
    path: "/main",
    element: <MainLayout />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "hotpicks",
        element: <HotPicks />,
        errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
      },
    ],
  },
]);

export default router;
```

Comment: what is your aim?

Comment: When I tested it again, if I coded as below, app.jsx worked even though the router was moved.


However, one more question is, I want to know what to do to make the html tags overlap instead of sequentially stacking up. The final goal is to keep the video running on the background screen.

Comment: ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <>
    <App />
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
    
  </>,
)